# footer error in IE with Symfony2.7 and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, symfony-2.7

My doubt is about CSS. I make this [web](http://s525081027.mialojamiento.es/symfony_demo/web/es/acceso/) to learn about symfony but don't work with IE . The IE browser put the footer in the midle of the page. I use Bootstrap ans Symfony 2.7.
 I try to find some  some error but I can't find a good answer.  Please can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 isn't liking the flex:1 on the .body-container. 
It looks like adding this to the .body-container will fix it:

`-ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;`

Found the fix on this : https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1301

Comment: Thanks, thanks a lot.  It is really works!  I can't thank you enough!